# open a webpage in IE using c#

Tags: c#

How to open a webpage in IE while clicking a button in a c# application.
My intention is to create a web login for a c# application which need to be opened in IE , in specified width and height, and needs to call a function in the application program.

Comment: A function as in a JavaScript function in the web application?

Comment: The only way I know to have your C# code interact with the DOM on the *client* side is by embedding the IE in WinForm as a controller.
Otherwise, you may write your IE add-on that will do this for you
If all you want is to call a JavaScript function you may use the option I suggested below (as answer) and use a parameter in the URL to do so

Comment: If you want to do remote authentication of some kind, you want a web service surely? What you're proposing seems a tad unusual (not that I want to discourage you from investigating unusual things).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(VS.71).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shell for the sample.
    /// </summary>
    public class MyProcess
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens the Internet Explorer application.
        /// </summary>
        public void OpenApplication(string myFavoritesPath)
        {
            // Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe");

            // Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
            Process.Start(myFavoritesPath);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer.
        /// </summary>
        public void OpenWithArguments()
        {
            // url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
            // by passing them as arguments.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

            // Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.asp");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes, both in a minimized 
        /// mode.
        /// </summary>
        public void OpenWithStartInfo()
        {

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            Process.Start(startInfo);

            startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

            Process.Start(startInfo);

        }

        public static void Main()
        {
                    // Get the path that stores favorite links.
                    string myFavoritesPath = 
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites);

                    MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();

            myProcess.OpenApplication(myFavoritesPath);
            myProcess.OpenWithArguments();
            myProcess.OpenWithStartInfo();

               }    
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you  Tzury , but i have updated the question with all my need  plz have a look on it

Comment: The only way I know to have your C# code interact with the DOM on the client side is by embedding the IE in WinForm as a controller. Otherwise, you may write your IE add-on that will do this for you If all you want is to call a JavaScript function you may use the option I suggested below (as answer) and use a parameter in the URL to do so – Tzury 3 mins ago  [delete this comment]

Answer (score 19):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to open a page in default browser    `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);`

If you want specifically to open it in IE you will probably need to create a new IE process with URL as an argument.

**UPD:** If you want to run a function, insert GET parameters into your url string (ie. `http://stackoverflow.com/page?runFunction=1`) and in your application code check for runFunction parameter and based on its value decide if your application needs to run the function.

I don't think is possible to specify new IE window width and height values, you may need to use javascript for that.

Comment: THIS IS THE RIGHT ANSWER: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url), using the default browser and avoid many other factors related to systems, installations, and customizations.