# open a page in IE using c#

Tags: c#

I'm opening a webpage in IE using c#

**Code:**

`Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");`

But, how can I resize the page with the following characteritics: `toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width='622', height='582'`

Comment: Do you need to start an actual instance of IE, or can you use something like the WebBrowser class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: Well, What I want is just open a new window in IE. But I need open this new window resized. I need that this page is opened in IE

Comment: Check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431115/open-a-webpage-in-ie-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For that level of fine grained control which I do not believe is available from the command line add a reference (COM) to *Microsoft Internet Controls* and then you can:

```
var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
object URL = "http://www.northwindtraders.com";

IE.ToolBar = 0;
IE.StatusBar = false;
IE.MenuBar = false;
IE.Width = 622;
IE.Height = 582;
IE.Visible = true;

IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
```

Comment: can you please show examples on how to use this technique (i want to pass a username and a password)

Answer (score 1):

These are the features for opening Internet Explorer from Command Shell:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) property to set some startup parameters.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for what options are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a reference to SHDocVw, by using the COM-object directly:

```
const int FormWidth = 800;
const int FormHeight = 600;


// http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/51998/opening-a-browser-and-hiding-the-address-bar-help.aspx
// http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2005/Apr/29/Previewing-HTML-with-InternetExplorerApplication-in-C
// http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab6969c7-0a34-4d88-9a74-b66888d3d88f/ie-automation-navigating-the-soup

// http://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar
public void OpenBrowserWindow(string strURL)
{
    // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strURL)
    // For Internet Explorer you can use -k (kiosk mode):
    // iexplore.exe -k http://www.google.com/
    // Internet Explorer Command-Line Options 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx
    // Starts Internet Explorer in kiosk mode. The browser opens in a maximized window that does not display the address bar, 
    // the navigation buttons, or the status bar.

    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/capture-the-screen-shot-using-net
    int posX = rect.Width - FormWidth;
    int posY = rect.Height - FormHeight;
    posX = Convert.ToInt32 (posX / 2.0);
    posY = Convert.ToInt32 (posY / 2.0);

    posX = Math.Max (posX, 0);
    posY = Math.Max (posY, 0);



    System.Type oType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID ("InternetExplorer.Application");

    object o = System.Activator.CreateInstance (oType);
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("MenuBar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { 0 });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("ToolBar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { 0 });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("StatusBar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { 0 });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("AddressBar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { 0 });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Visible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { true });


    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Top", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { posY });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Left", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { posX });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Width", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { FormWidth });
    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Height", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { FormHeight });

    o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("Navigate", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, new object[] { strURL });

    try 
    {
        object ohwnd = o.GetType ().InvokeMember ("hwnd", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, o, null);
        System.IntPtr IEHwnd = (System.IntPtr)ohwnd;
        // NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow (IEHwnd);
        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(IEHwnd, NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMaximized);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

} // OpenBrowserWindow



public class NativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, WindowShowStyle nCmdShow);


    /// <summary>Enumeration of the different ways of showing a window using
    /// ShowWindow</summary>
    public enum WindowShowStyle : int
    {
        /// <summary>Hides the window and activates another window.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_HIDE</remarks>
        Hide = 0,
        /// <summary>Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized
        /// or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and
        /// position. An application should specify this flag when displaying
        /// the window for the first time.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNORMAL</remarks>
        ShowNormal = 1,
        /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMINIMIZED</remarks>
        ShowMinimized = 2,
        /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED</remarks>
        ShowMaximized = 3,
        /// <summary>Maximizes the specified window.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_MAXIMIZE</remarks>
        Maximize = 3,
        /// <summary>Displays a window in its most recent size and position.
        /// This value is similar to "ShowNormal", except the window is not
        /// actived.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE</remarks>
        ShowNormalNoActivate = 4,
        /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it in its current size
        /// and position.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOW</remarks>
        Show = 5,
        /// <summary>Minimizes the specified window and activates the next
        /// top-level window in the Z order.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_MINIMIZE</remarks>
        Minimize = 6,
        /// <summary>Displays the window as a minimized window. This value is
        /// similar to "ShowMinimized", except the window is not activated.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE</remarks>
        ShowMinNoActivate = 7,
        /// <summary>Displays the window in its current size and position. This
        /// value is similar to "Show", except the window is not activated.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNA</remarks>
        ShowNoActivate = 8,
        /// <summary>Activates and displays the window. If the window is
        /// minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size
        /// and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring
        /// a minimized window.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_RESTORE</remarks>
        Restore = 9,
        /// <summary>Sets the show state based on the SW_ value specified in the
        /// STARTUPINFO structure passed to the CreateProcess function by the
        /// program that started the application.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWDEFAULT</remarks>
        ShowDefault = 10,
        /// <summary>Windows 2000/XP: Minimizes a window, even if the thread
        /// that owns the window is hung. This flag should only be used when
        /// minimizing windows from a different thread.</summary>
        /// <remarks>See SW_FORCEMINIMIZE</remarks>
        ForceMinimized = 11
    }

}
```

You can also use VirtualScreen

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
```

instead of PrimaryScreen

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use window messages this is thrown together from PInvoke.net

```
void Main()
{
 Process p = Process.Start( 
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" , "www.google.com" );

 while(p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero )
 {
  Thread.Sleep(100);
  p.Refresh();
 }

 SetWindowPos( p.MainWindowHandle , IntPtr.Zero , 100 , 100, 800 ,400 , SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow ); 


}




// Define other methods and classes here
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

/// <summary>
/// Window handles (HWND) used for hWndInsertAfter
/// </summary>
public static class HWND
{
   public static IntPtr
   NoTopMost = new IntPtr(-2),
   TopMost = new IntPtr(-1),
   Top = new IntPtr(0),
   Bottom = new IntPtr(1);
}

/// <summary>
/// SetWindowPos Flags
/// </summary>
public static class SWP
{
   public static readonly int
   NOSIZE = 0x0001,
   NOMOVE = 0x0002,
   NOZORDER = 0x0004,
   NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
   NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
   DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
   FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
   SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
   HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
   NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
   NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
   NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
   NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
   DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
   ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
}

[Flags()]
private enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    /// <summary>If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, 
    /// the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from 
    /// blocking its execution while other threads process the request.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS</remarks>
    AsynchronousWindowPosition = 0x4000,
    /// <summary>Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_DEFERERASE</remarks>
    DeferErase = 0x2000,
    /// <summary>Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_DRAWFRAME</remarks>
    DrawFrame = 0x0020,
    /// <summary>Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to 
    /// the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE 
    /// is sent only when the window's size is being changed.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_FRAMECHANGED</remarks>
    FrameChanged = 0x0020,
    /// <summary>Hides the window.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_HIDEWINDOW</remarks>
    HideWindow = 0x0080,
    /// <summary>Does not activate the window. If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the 
    /// top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter 
    /// parameter).</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOACTIVATE</remarks>
    DoNotActivate = 0x0010,
    /// <summary>Discards the entire contents of the client area. If this flag is not specified, the valid 
    /// contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or 
    /// repositioned.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOCOPYBITS</remarks>
    DoNotCopyBits = 0x0100,
    /// <summary>Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOMOVE</remarks>
    IgnoreMove = 0x0002,
    /// <summary>Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOOWNERZORDER</remarks>
    DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder = 0x0200,
    /// <summary>Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to 
    /// the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent 
    /// window uncovered as a result of the window being moved. When this flag is set, the application must 
    /// explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOREDRAW</remarks>
    DoNotRedraw = 0x0008,
    /// <summary>Same as the SWP_NOOWNERZORDER flag.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOREPOSITION</remarks>
    DoNotReposition = 0x0200,
    /// <summary>Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOSENDCHANGING</remarks>
    DoNotSendChangingEvent = 0x0400,
    /// <summary>Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOSIZE</remarks>
    IgnoreResize = 0x0001,
    /// <summary>Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_NOZORDER</remarks>
    IgnoreZOrder = 0x0004,
    /// <summary>Displays the window.</summary>
    /// <remarks>SWP_SHOWWINDOW</remarks>
    ShowWindow = 0x0040,
}
```