# Run IE11 in Hidden Mode

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a requirement to run IE11 in hidden mode (Without showing the browser) so I can descretely set a cookie. This is the code I previously used which worked in IE9

```
            cmd = (String)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IE.AssocFile.HTM\shell\opennew\command", "", null);
            url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = cmd,
                Arguments = url,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            });
```

If I use this on a machine with IE11 it shows the browser. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13030612/246342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suggest you a different way to set a cookie:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
```

You can find below an example to use it:

```
bool b = InternetSetCookie("http://localhost/", "keyname", "value; Expires = + DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToString("R"));
```

Comment: This is very interesting - Is there anyway to make this work with Chrome and Firefox or is this explicitly for IE?

Comment: Unfortunately it is specific for IE :(

Comment: I've created a POC and its working in IE as expected. Even though it doesn't support other browsers, It's still extremely useful & I will probably go down this route. Thank you